# Pandas dataframe from nested dictionary adding dict key to own column

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I have a nested dictionary with over 10,000 accounts. I need a robust solution. The below is an example that needs to be scaled to n.

The nested dictionary looks like this with the acct # as the keys:

```
 {'Acct301':                     
                  ds         trend      yhat         y
 0   2018-05-01 00:00:00  1.268612    0.679369    2.554900       
 1   2018-05-01 01:00:00  1.268372    0.089233    2.022369      
 2   2018-05-01 02:00:00  1.268132   -0.256185    1.640524    

 [744 rows x 19 columns],

'Acct2':        
          ds                trend       yhat          y  
 0   2018-05-01 00:00:00  0.575119   -0.456240    1.26193       
 1   2018-05-01 01:00:00  0.575140   -0.687562    1.033594       
 2   2018-05-01 02:00:00  0.575161   -0.795286    0.906530  
[744 rows x 19 columns]}
```

I need the dataframe to have the account # in it's own column.

I tried the following code:

```
df= pd.concat(dict.values(), ignore_index= True)
```

This output almost works but there is no Acct#, I get the following :

```
             ds            trend       yhat         y  
 0  2018-05-01 00:00:00  1.268612    0.679369    2.554900        
 1  2018-05-01 01:00:00  1.268372    0.089233    2.022369
 2  2018-05-01 02:00:00  0.575161   -0.795286    0.906530 
 3  2018-05-01 00:00:00  0.575119   -0.456240    1.26193       
 4  2018-05-01 01:00:00  0.575140   -0.687562    1.033594       
 5  2018-05-01 02:00:00  0.575161   -0.795286    0.906530
```

My desired output looks like this

```
    Acct #          ds            trend       yhat         y  
 0   Acct1   2018-05-01 00:00:00  1.268612    0.679369    2.554900        
 1   Acct1   2018-05-01 01:00:00  1.268372    0.089233    2.022369
 2   Acct1   2018-05-01 02:00:00  0.575161   -0.795286    0.906530 
 3   Acct2   2018-05-01 00:00:00  0.575119   -0.456240    1.26193       
 4   Acct2   2018-05-01 01:00:00  0.575140   -0.687562    1.033594       
 5   Acct2   2018-05-01 02:00:00  0.575161   -0.795286    0.906530
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume dictionary is `d`. Use option `keys` of `pd.concat` with some clean-up commands

```
df = (pd.concat(d.values(), keys=d.keys())
        .reset_index()
        .drop('level_1',1).rename(columns={'level_0': 'Acct#'}))

Out[207]:
   Acct#                   ds     trend      yhat         y
0  Acct1  2018-05-01 00:00:00  1.268612  0.679369  2.554900
1  Acct1  2018-05-01 01:00:00  1.268372  0.089233  2.022369
2  Acct1  2018-05-01 02:00:00  1.268132 -0.256185  1.640524
3  Acct2  2018-05-01 00:00:00  0.575119 -0.456240  1.261930
4  Acct2  2018-05-01 01:00:00  0.575140 -0.687562  1.033594
5  Acct2  2018-05-01 02:00:00  0.575161 -0.795286  0.906530
```